# mkdir and recursive copy in php

Tags: php, copy, mkdir, shell-exec, recursive-datastructures

My function is having problems creating and copying the contents to the new directory (also I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, so alternate suggestions are welcome).

I have 2 network drives mounted via `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
//128.251.108.xxx/Data/Agilent_Data /home/lv_admin/uslonsnas001 cifs cred=/etc/.na02passwd,rw,umask=0000,uid=www-data,gid=webgroup 0 0
//128.251.108.xx/c$/Agilent /home/lv_admin/uslonsapp003 cifs cred=/etc/.na02passwd,rw,umask=0000,uid=www-data,gid=webgroup 0 0
```

Basically, when prompted with a file path from `uslonsapp003` mount I check to see if the directory structure exists in `uslonsnas001` and create the recursive directory if not.  Then I copy the content from `uslonsapp003` to the new structure location in `uslonsnas001`.  Here is my code:

```
$pImagePath = "http://uslonsapp003:8080/boardtests/2011/4/29/12/30/8051/Images/E_1-c274.jpg";
//strip off the path name up to '2011' and take off the image name at the end
    $startpos = strpos( $pImagePath, "/boardtests/" ) + strlen( "/boardtests/" );
    $endpos   = strpos( $pImagePath, "/Images/" );
    $file_dir = substr( $pImagePath, $startpos, ( $endpos - $startpos ) );
    $orig_dir = "/home/lv_admin/uslonsapp003/ITFSS/DataStore/BoardTest/" . $file_dir;
    $new_dir  = "/home/lv_admin/uslonsnas001/BoardTest/" . $file_dir;
    if( !is_dir( $new_dir ) )
        if( !shell_exec("mkdir -p $new_dir") )    return array( "status" => 0, "errordesc" => "failed to make dir: '" . $new_dir . "'" );
    if( !shell_exec("cp -r $orig_dir $new_dir") ) return array( "status" => 0, "errordesc" => "failed to copy from: '" . $orig_dir . "' to: '" . $new_dir . "'" );
    return array( "status" => 1 );
```

I've been getting both errors, 'failed to make dir...' and 'failed to copy from...'

This is executed through Apache, I'm assuming it's a permissions problem but thats just my 'hunch'.  Please help!

I've tried adding `sudo` to the beginning of the shell_exec()'s but that still doesn't work.

**UPATED1**

I figured out that the mkdir was failing because when I created the `/home/lv_admin/uslonsnas001` directory I didn't change the mod, owner, and group on it to the one that would be using it (www-data).   Doing the following fixed that part:

```
$ sudo chmod 775 ~/uslonsnas001
$ sudo chown www-data ~/uslonsnas001
$ sudo chgrp webgroup ~/uslonsnas001
```

But I'm still having problems with the copy command, now saying "Module 'ODBC' already Loaded"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem was simple.  My original mount point was not setup with write permissions for root. After changing the mount point owner and group to root it works.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
mkdir("path/to/your/directory", 0777, true);
```

where 0777 is chmod and bool true activate recursive mode

Comment: I get the same error when using mkdir(), although I can't tell what the php error is.  Is there an error recovery name for an error thrown by mkdir() that I can print?

Comment: maybe your problem comes from root directories permission into your network drives. Check access user to theses root directories, it may be created by an another user than root

Comment: check my OP again, my fstab lines show that I'm mounting it using the www-data user.  But this hasn't posed a problem in that past, I have other programs that create files (granted I've never created directories).

Comment: look at [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=641326), it can help u

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help.  All that tells me is that my umask in my fstab mount point is correct and I should be able to write to the mount.

Comment: I ended up using the function found here: http://codestips.com/php-copy-directory-from-source-to-destination/ for my copy command.

Comment: "Module 'ODBC' already Loaded" is linked to a conf file, try to comment it somewhere